# Why are there Inconsistencies with Error Code 11200

Tags: twilio, error-log, insight

1. On the Error Log page, transactions sometimes appear with an error icon (diamond) and sometimes with a warning icon (triangle). What determines which icon?
2. When I go to Messaging Insights and select Delivery and Errors, then select Error Code, 11200 does not appear in the graph along with the other error codes. Why not?
3. I have an alert that emails me if there are more than three 11200 errors in 5 minutes. Periodically, when I check out the details on an alert, all I see is either 1 transaction or may even no transactions in the Error Log for the time specified in the email. What am I not understanding?